# How to keep selections in array when view dismiss SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I keep my filter selections when view dismiss . Im trying to make a filter pop up view but I couldn't figure out how to keep my selections when user press filter button. Selections array where I put my filter selections. When user press filter button my popup view will dismiss and I want to display user selections when filter view open again.

```
struct FilterPopUpView: View {

@State var filterListArray : [ProductListSortAndFilterList]
@Binding var popUpOpened : Bool
@State var selections : [String] = []
@State var isApply : Bool = false
@State var isMarked : Bool = false
@State var filterApply : Bool = false
@Environment (\.presentationMode) var Presentation


var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        ZStack{
            List {
                ForEach(filterListArray.filter{ $0.id != "sort" && $0.id != "stock"}, id:\.id) { data in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination : FilterDetailView(filterDetailList: data.sortAndFilterList ?? [], navigationBarTitle: data.name ?? "", selectionFilters: $selections, isApply: $isApply, selectSingle: data.selectSingle ?? 1)
                                    
                    ){
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing:10){
                            
                            FilterCell(filterType: data)
                            
                            HStack{
                                
                                ForEach(selections, id:\.self ) { item in
                                    
                                    if isApply == true {
                                        
                                        SelectedFiltersRow(filterSelection: item, sortAndFilterData: data)

                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                ForEach(filterListArray , id:\.id) { item in
                    
                    if item.name == "Stoktakiler" {
                        
                        HStack {
                            
                            FilterCell(filterType: item)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            CheckBoxField(isMarked: $isMarked)
                            
                        }.contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            
                            isMarked.toggle()
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Filtrele"),displayMode: .inline)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Temizle")
                    {
                        
                        self.selections.removeAll()
                        isMarked = false
                        
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel")
                    {
                        print("Cancel tapped!")
                        
                        popUpOpened = false
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
               
                filterApply == true
                self.Presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                
            }) {
                
                FilterButton()
                
            }.offset(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * (0.4))
            
        }.onAppear {
       
            print(selections)
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store the state at least one level up in your view hierarchy and then pass it to `FilterPopUpView` as a parameter.

I'd probably encapsulate all of the filter state in one struct like:

```
struct FilterState {
  var selections : [String] = []
  var isApply : Bool = false
  isMarked : Bool = false
  var filterApply : Bool = false
}
```

Then, store that as a @State on your parent view:

```
@State private var filterState = FilterState()
```

And on your `FilterPopUpView`:

```
@Binding var filterState : FilterState
```

And then pass it as a parameter when you open the popup. That way, it'll retain state between openings.